# Logs in Spring Boot not showing in terminal

Tags: spring-boot, slf4j

I have a project in `Spring Boot` where I am adding logs with the `@Slf4j` annotation, but I can't get them to show up in the terminal when starting the project.

This is the log: `log.info("totalVacations: " + totalVacations);`

When I run the command `mvn spring-boot`: run, in terminal I can't see the message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Very likely you are missing the configuration of the appender, if you are also using **LOG4J** and you don't already have it, you can create a file named: `log4j2.xml` within the application's class path, and then create some basic configuration like:

```
<Configuration>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout
                pattern="%style{%d{ISO8601}}{black} %highlight{%-5level }[%style{%t}{bright,blue}] %style{%C{1.}}{bright,yellow}: %msg%n%throwable" />
        </Console>

        <RollingFile name="RollingFile"
            fileName="./logs/spring-boot-logger-log4j2.log"
            filePattern="./logs/$${date:yyyy-MM}/spring-boot-logger-log4j2-%d{-dd-MMMM-yyyy}-%i.log.gz">
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>%d %p %C{1.} [%t] %m%n</pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <!-- rollover on startup, daily and when the file reaches 
                    10 MegaBytes -->
                <OnStartupTriggeringPolicy />
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
                    size="10 MB" />
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
            </Policies>
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <!-- LOG everything at INFO level -->
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
            <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile" />
        </Root>

        <!-- LOG "com.baeldung*" at TRACE level -->
        <Logger name="com.baeldung" level="trace"></Logger>
    </Loggers>

</Configuration>
```

The key here is to set an appender to the console so that the logs are pushed there, and then at the logger section establish which level are you trying to get at the console appender, according to your example that should be INFO

If you are using just plain **SLF4J** with **Logback** go to `src/main/resources/application.properties` and add the following line:

```
logging.level.com=INFO
```

The ".com" is referencing the package to where this will apply, in this case is everything inside src/main/java/com.

and at the `logback-spring.xml` try this basic config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml"/>
    <logger name="your.name" level="INFO" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
        <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
    </logger>
 </configuration>
```

You can find a very nice tutorial with more info here:

- https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-logging
- https://springframework.guru/using-logback-spring-boot/

Comment: I am using the ``@Slf4j`` annotation, I have added the file ``log4j2.xml`` with the same configuration and I have added in the ``application.yml`` ``logging.level.com = INFO``. But I still can't see the log in either the terminal or the console.

Comment: Can you set debug=true in your application.properties and see if that helps ?

Comment: This is what I have in my application.yml but it doesn't work: ```debug: true
logging:
  level:
    liquibase: DEBUG```

Comment: I see one last try that comes to my mind is to add logging.level.root=info

Comment: I still do not see the logs in the terminal, I am using the @Slf4j annotation, and I put in the application.yml logging:level:root: INFO

Comment: I have added the xml file to the question in case there is something else to do

Comment: For what I see now, you are using logback not log4j, change the content of the file to what I included in the answer and see if that helps, I also included another link that migh help you

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand, what I want is to show logs in the terminal with the @ Slf4j annotation. Do I have to use the log4j2.xml file, the logback-spring.xml file, or both?

Comment: In reality you don't need any of the xml files, log4j and logback are log implementations, build on top of basic logging, they have their respective xml configuration files. I thought you where using one of them it seems not. Did you tried the suggestion from the other answer, to change LOG to log?

Comment: Yes, but it shows me an error in ``log``: ``log cannot be resolved``

Comment: I have fixed the problem. I'm using the ``@Slf4j`` annotation and the ``log.info ("totalVacations:" + totalVacations);`` log. But I still don't see the message in the terminal. What else do I need to do or what remains to be added?

Comment: Do you have a repo I can take a look at?

Comment: No, I only have it locally. But the only thing I have in the class is the @ Slf4j annotation and the log inside a method. Is there something else to add? How do I start the project to show logs?

Answer (score 1):

Check whether @Slf4J import is from Lombok or some other library. I'm sure lombok @Slf4J default provides lowercase log and not LOG.

Comment: This is the import: `import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;`

Comment: Do you have any config file specific to logging? Try searching for "appender" keyword in your entire project.

Comment: I have the ``log4j2.xml`` file as in the other answer

Comment: then you should use @Log4j2 lombok annotation.

Comment: What I want to achieve is to show logs with the annotation @Slf4j by the terminal or by the console

Comment: log4j and slf4j are two different implementation of logging mechanisms. setup is for log4j , but trying to log using Slf4j. So, change log4j2 to some logback xml

Comment: Ok yes, I know that, but I want to be able to write logs in the terminal using @ Slf4j

Comment: can you rename your log4j2.xml to something like logback-spring.xml. Also, please do share you log4j2.xml file to see what appenders are setup for your logs.